# Is it possible to have a custom url for a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile and was wondering what I would need to do in order to get access to it from my host machine by visiting `myapp.dev`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install apt-utils -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
    apache2 php7.0 php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php7.0 curl lynx-cur git

EXPOSE 80

ADD www /var/www/site

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND

EXPOSE 80
```

I am using the following command to run the container:

`docker run -d -p 8080:80`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to be able to resolve it locally you could add an alias for localhost in your `hosts` file.

1. Locate your `hosts` file.

   - Linux: `/etc/hosts`
   - MacOS: `/private/etc/hosts`
   - Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
2. Add this line at the end of the file:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 myapp.dev
   ```

Now you can access your container using `myapp.dev:8080`.

Comment: Is it possible to get this url without port?